# Visual C++ how to load .DLL from other company

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dllimport, rundll32

I need to load a .dll file from another company code in order for me to call its function. But how do I load it when I dont know how to set its variable? The dll file is "Interop.OphirLMMeasurementLib.dll" and this is the cut out from data sheet.

> "The OphirLMMeasurement COM object follows the standard COM practice
>   of returning an HRESULT from its methods. The HRESULT can be passed to
>   GetErrorFromCode to get a descriptive string, or the standard COM
>   GetErrorInfo function can be called (see documentation for your
>   environment). Some client environments (such as VB6 and all .NET
>   languages) do not return this HRESULT from the method call; instead
>   they throw an exception when a method returns a failure HRESULT. This
>   exception will normally contain within it the error number and the
>   descriptive string.
>
> ```
> ----------
>
>
> 3.3 Methods and Events
>
> 3.3.1 Device Communications
> ```
>
> Close
>
> CloseAll
>
> GetKnownWirelessDevices
>
> OpenUSBDevice
>
> OpenWirelessDevice
>
> ResetAllDevices
>
> ResetDevice
>
> ScanUSB
>
> ScanWireless

So how do I call the function of ScanUSB from this .dll file?

Comment: Did they not provide a header and import library with the DLL? The latter you don't *strictly* need, but it would seem helpful they would at least provide the former. You may want to check the package the DLL came in.

Comment: The Interop library was meant for a .NET program.  In native C++ you'll have to use the #import directive to import the type library.  Usually embedded in the DLL.  There is a learning curve to writing COM client code in C++, you'd be better off using a .NET language.

Comment: They did not provide any header and import library method, but they did provide a usable demo for VB, Csharp, matlab and labview which i'm not familiar with. I was given the task to use only C++ and no other language.

Answer (score 0):

The important word is **COM**. Short for Component Object Model, this is Microsoft's language-neutral mechanism to call methods on objects.

In this case, `ScanUSB` is a method on objects of the `OphirLMMeasurement` type. I don't know from just this bit how to get such an object - `CreateInstance` is the likely way. I suspect `OpenUSBDevice` will be necessary then, before `ScanUSB`. But we'd also need to know the arguments, and you left out those parts of the documentation.

Comment: The only document that they provide is this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6i8z6exfoa1swv/OphirLMMeasurement%20COM%20Object.pdf?dl=0

and I must need to use C++ language